# Image isn't bound to the UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a UIImageView in created in Inspector that I resize in my code based on a selected image which i get from the web. However on first load of the image, it's being displayed in the images normal resolution instead of the UIImageViews newly created bounds.

Resizing the UIImageView:

```
fullScreenImage.bounds.size = CGSize(width: scaledWidth, height: scaledHeight)
```

Setting the UIImageView's image

```
let imageStringURL = images[indexPath.row].urls!["regular"]
let imageURL = URL(string: imageStringURL!)!
let imageData = try! Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
fullScreenImage.image = image
```

This is how it looks when the image is first clicked on to enter "fullscreen mode"
[image]

This is how it looks the second time i click it

[image]

Not really sure why the Image isn't bounding itself within the specified UIImageView bounds

Answer (score 0):

Instead of resizing the bound, you can set the UIViewContentMode property of UIImageView. This will resize the imageView image to fit inside the bounds.

fullScreenImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

Comment: Just tried it, didn't seem to fix it. The problem is I'm getting these images from an API online and there's many with different aspect ratios. I have to keep the original aspect ratio of the image when i display it, so i have to make the Image fit the changed UIImageView. 

I'm also changing device orientations and need to update the UIImageView to account for the aspect ratios

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround solution. I tried setting the contentMode to aspect fit, and i also tried enabling clip to bounds in the inspector, however none of them worked. So I simply looked into just resizing the UIImage itself and placing it into the UIImageView.
I found an extension in another post for a UIImage that resizes it

```
extension UIImage{
    func resizeImage(newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        // Guard newSize is different
        guard self.size != newSize else { return self }

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0);
        self.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height))
        let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage
    }
}
```

**If anyone knows of a better way please let me know :)**